# Solving for a variable inside a limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm wondering how to solve for a variable inside a limit:

My textbook defines $e$ implicitly as the number such that 
$$e\iff\displaystyle{\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}}=1$$

I know from elsewhere $e$ can also be defined differently:

$$e=\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}$$

I'm wondering how to solve for $e$ in the first definition. Can the second definition be derived from the first?

To solve for $e$ in the first definition, my initial direction would be to try and algebraically remove the limit on the left side of the equation. I can't see any way of doing this and don't have any other tricks up my sleeve. It would be enlightening if some other tricks are suggested or if my assumptions are told to be false.

Comment: Your first limit is really the limit definition of derivative applied to the e-power function, where it is assumed that the derivative of $e^x$ is known to be $e^x$, and $e^0=1$. This has to be dealt with somewhere earlier in your textbook, which brings us to precisely your second limit. That can be derived from the notion that the derivative of $lnx$ is $1/x$ and at $x=1$, that derivative would be $1$. Using the limit definition of the derivative of $lnx$ at $x=1$ will give you that second limit. Remember that $e^x$ and $lnx$ are inverses.

Comment: I'm sorry – I cant extrapolate from your comment. Would you mind explaining in full detail?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "How to solve e in the first definition". I think the main question is: How is the Natural Log introduced in your course? As an area under the curve $y=1/x$ or as an inverse of an earlier introduced function $y=e^x$?

Comment: I meant to say how to extract an explicit definition of e from the first definition. I was hoping it would end up looking like the second definition. The natural log was introduced as the inverse of $y=e^x$.

Comment: I do not immediately see how from the first limit you can algebraically go to the second (maybe someone else can weigh in here). In my view, that is because the first limit is the limit based on the e-power function and the second limit is achieved through $lnx$, both on which the limit definition of the derivative is applied. Do you know how that was done in the second case?

Comment: @imranfat The $1$ in the first limit is certainly correct. After all, the derivative of $e^x$ at $x=0$ is $1$....

Comment: @AlexG. Point well taken, I read the limit as equal to $e$ because of the double arrow. (So I misread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I know exactly what you're saying and I had that trouble too.

So we have:

$$e\iff\displaystyle{\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}}=1$$

$$e=\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}$$

Let's examine the second one and do some manipulation:
$n = 1/h$

$$e=\lim_{h\to0}\left(1+h\right)^{1/h}$$

If we look at small values of $h$,

$$e \approx (1+h)^{1/h}$$

Therefore,

$$e^h \approx 1+h$$

Replace this with $e^h$ in our first limit.

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h+1-1}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h}{h} = 1$$

Answer (score 2):

Let us define the sequence
\begin{align}
a_n = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n
\end{align}
then it's not hard to see that
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\leq \left( 1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}
\end{align}
but I will not do the calculation here. Moreover, the sequence it bounded since
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n =\sum^n_{k=0}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}=\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{1}{k!}\left( 1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right).
\end{align}
Using the fact that $2^{k-1}\leq k!$ for $k=2, 3, \ldots$ and
\begin{align}
\left( 1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right) \leq 1
\end{align}
 we see that
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n \leq \sum^n_{k=0} \frac{1}{2^{k-1}} \leq \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}<\infty. 
\end{align}
Thus, it follows $a_n$ converges to some number $a$.

Back to the problem. Since the limit
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^h-1}{h} = 1
\end{align}
holds, then
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n(e^{1/n}-1) = 1
\end{align}
where we replaced $h$ with $1/n$. Next, observe
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} [n(e^{1/n}-1)-n(a_n^{1/n}-1)] = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n(e^{1/n}-a_n^{1/n})=0
\end{align}
since
\begin{align}
n(a_n^{1/n}-1) = 1.
\end{align}
Finally, we have
\begin{align}
|e-a_n| = |e^{n/n}-a_n^{n/n}|= |e^{1/n}-a_n^{1/n}|\left|\sum^{n-1}_{k=0} e^{k/n}a_n^{(n-1-k)/n} \right|\leq n|e^{1/n}-a_n^{1/n}|\max\{e, a\}\rightarrow 0
\end{align}
as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Thus, $a_n \rightarrow e$.

Comment: I think you meant $h \to 0$ in your first limit.

Comment: Yes. I have made the correction.

Comment: Nice (and novel) approach. +1